# How to make Hamburger Menu Transition Animation in XAML only

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, hamburger-menu

I want to create the Hamburger Menu Transition Animation in XAML only.
I only found tutorials and examples of how to do this with code-behind.
But this is something I want to avoid at all costs.

This is how the animation looks like:
[Animation (no direct GIF possible at the moment)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZAk2.gif)

[One example I found](https://github.com/Abel13/HamburgerMenu/tree/master/HamburgerMenu)

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="43.5"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-43.5"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle2">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="70"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="200"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="CloseMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="43.5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-43.5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle2">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="70"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

code-behind:

```
    private void ButtonMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(StateClosed)
        {
            Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("OpenMenu") as Storyboard;
            sb.Begin();
        }
        else
        {
            Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("CloseMenu") as Storyboard;
            sb.Begin();
        }

        StateClosed = !StateClosed;
    }
```

Is there anyway to achive the same result using XAML-only.
I dont want any code-behind for this animation...

I know how to create each Storyboard for the animation itself.
But the same button has to execute two different Storyboards,
depending on the state of the menu?

Comment: What exactly is "the Hamburger Menu Transition Animation"? Can you put an animation of it in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using a `ToggleButton` instead. Since the `ToggleButton` has built in `Checked` / `Unchecked` events, you can use those in `EventTrigger`s to run your storyboards.

```
<ToggleButton ... >
    <!-- Your menu icon XAML/rectangles go here -->
    <ToggleButton.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMenu}" />
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMenu}" />
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ToggleButton.Triggers>
</ToggleButton>
```